# Who is 'user' in Instagram Stories API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'm writing an web app which uses [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) for [Stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories). This is my preparation.

- I'm an admin `ME` of a Facebook page `FB`
- I have an Instagram account `IG`, which I [convert to a business account](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/#connect) and then [link to the Facebook](https://help.instagram.com/356902681064399) page `FB`.

Then I follow through the [instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/) on how to use Instagram Graph API.

- I made a Facebook login page for my app `APP`, as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started/#fblogin).
- It works fine: I can login with my admin ID/PW for `ME`, and my app returns an [access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

Now, the next step is to invoke [stories edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories) to extract the stories in an Instagram account `IG`. According to the documentation,

> To get all of an Instagram Business Account's stories, send a GET request to the `/user/stories` edge; for example,
>   `GET graph.facebook.com
>     /17841405822304914/stories`

---

**Question:** Who is the `user` in the `/user/stories` edge?

I naturally assume that it's my admin ID `ME` for the Facebook page `FB` because this page is linked to my target IG account `IG`. But when I tried to invoke `/user/stories` edge, I got an error.

```
{
  "error":{
    "message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (stories) on node type (User)",
    "type":"OAuthException",
    "code":100,
    "fbtrace_id":"FaeAydt7\/rd"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first GET `me/accounts` -> Submit

you should see your accounts, pick the one and click on account'd `id`

then add `instagram_business_account` as selected field -> Submit

you should see instagram account's id returned, click on it

GET `/{instagra_business_account_id}/stories` -> Submit